# Set LESS CSS color with PHP

Tags: php, css, session, colors, less

I have a PHP form that stores a 6 character hexdecimal color in a session variable.  Then at the top of the page in the head section I have

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['globalcolor']) {
    $globalcolor = $_SESSION['globalcolor'];
    echo "<style type='stylesheet/less'>";
    echo "@mainfirst: #" . $_SESSION['globalcolor'] . ";";
    echo "</style>";
}
?>
```

And all the colors in the stylesheet are based off of @mainfirst color variable in the LESS stylesheet.  But nothing changes when its printed.  How can I get it to accept the variable in the LESS stylesheet?

Comment: I haven't done much with LESS, but doesn't it need to be run through a compiler? I don't think you can just go `<style type="less">`

Comment: I think your best option if you want to use less would be to use a php less compiler like this one: http://leafo.net/lessphp/

Comment: if you are using a javascript implementation LESS in the browser (i.e. less.js) you can modify variables using the `less.modifyVars()` function. Read more here: [http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser). But using LESS client-side is not recommended in production ... and since you are using php you could look into lessphp, as @Brobin already suggested.

Answer (score -2):

less has to be compiled to turn into the css which a browser can understand. so you may be better off using plain css.

Comment: Instead of turning him away from less, how about point him in the right direction. There are php libraries that allow you to compile less fairly easily. How about try this one: http://leafo.net/lessphp/

Comment: sorry I didn't realise you could compile less client side.

Comment: You can compile less server side (with lessphp) or client side (with less.js)